# fit_generator in keras: where is the batch_size specified?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Hi I don't understand the keras fit_generator docs.

I hope my confusion is rational.

There is a `batch_size` and also the concept of training in in batches. Using `model_fit()`, I specify a `batch_size` of 128.

To me this means that my dataset will be fed in 128 samples at a time, thereby greatly alleviating memory. It should allow a 100 million sample dataset to be trained as long as I have got the time to wait. After all, keras is only "working with" 128 samples at a time. Right?

But I highly suspect that for specifying the `batch_size` alone doesn't do what I want whatsoever. Tons of memory is still being used.  For my goals I need to train in batches of 128 examples each.

So I am guessing this is what `fit_generator` does. I really want to ask why doesn't `batch_size` actually work as it's name suggests?

More importantly, if `fit_generator` is needed, where do I specify the `batch_size`? The docs say to loop indefinitely. 
A generator loops over every row once. How do I loop over 128 samples at a time and remember where I last stopped and recall it the next time that keras asks for the next batch's starting row number (would be row 129 after first batch is done).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to handle the batch size somehow inside the generator. Here is an example to generate random batches:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.arange(100)
data_lab = data%2
wholeData = np.array([data, data_lab])
wholeData = wholeData.T

def data_generator(all_data, batch_size = 20):

    while True:        

        idx = np.random.randint(len(all_data), size=batch_size)

        # Assuming the last column contains labels
        batch_x = all_data[idx, :-1]
        batch_y = all_data[idx, -1]

        # Return a tuple of (Xs,Ys) to feed the model
        yield(batch_x, batch_y)

print([x for x in data_generator(wholeData)])
```

Answer (score 0):

First, keras batch_size does work very well. If you are working on GPU, you should know that the model can be very heavy with keras, especially if you are using recurrent cells. If you are working on CPU, the whole program is loaded in memory, the batch size won't have much of an impact on the memory. If you are using `fit()`, the whole dataset is probably loaded in memory, keras produces batches at every step. It's very difficult to predict the amount of memory that will be used.

As for the `fit_generator()` method, you should build a python generator function (using `yield` instead of `return`), yielding one batch at every step. The `yield` should be in an infinite loop (we often use `while true:` ...).

Do you have some code to illustrate your problem?